# Windows 8 time triggered background tasks

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I would like to perform a background task every 8 hours (more frequently is fine). Is it true that if the computer is turned off or hibernating when the background task is supposed to execute, it just skips that iteration?

Assuming that it does, my next requirement would be to schedule it when the computer comes out of hibernation or is turned on. The latter is simple; I can schedule a system triggered background task for when a session begins. But I'm not sure how to handle the case when the user "un-hibernates" the computer. Any suggestions on this one? The UserPresent trigger looks promising, but I haven't been able to find any definition for when that gets fired.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/05/24/being-productive-in-the-background-background-tasks.aspx#10318589

So no, the TimeTrigger would probably be skipped if the system is sleeping/hibernating.

Available conditions can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.systemconditiontype

I would suggest that you create two background tasks (I don't have much experience with background tasks, so I'm not even sure how possible this is). One for the TimeTrigger and another that runs using the UserPresent condition. If a TimeTrigger runs successfully, store a flag or value with the last run time somewhere, and when the second task is about to run, check this flag/last run time and then abort or continue as may be required.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion would be to download the following SDK sample:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Task-Sample-9209ade9

Run the sample, register a background task using a TimeTrigger, and hibernate the machine shortly before the task is set to complete. Then, wait long enough for the task timer to have expired, and restore the machine (keeping the sample app running), and switch back to the sample app and see if the task completed.

That should tell you whether the task will execute upon resume.